# In R, grab & return loaded dataframe variable with dynamic name

Tags: r

We have a directory with files `data1.rda`, `data2.rda`, `data3.rda` and the following function in R to load and return the data. `load(data1.rda)` returns a dataframe named `data1`, with the same naming pattern for other .rda files loaded:

```
returnData <- function(id) { 
  load(paste0("data", id, ".rda"))
  return(paste0("data", id))
}

data1 <- returnData(1)
```

Obviously the above doesn't work because the string `data1` is returned rather than the dataframe. How can we return the named dataframe `data1` in the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
returnData <- function(id) { 
  load(paste0("data", id, ".rda"))
  return(eval(parse(text = paste0("data", id))))
}

data1 <- returnData(1)
```

Comment: yes this appears to work. Clean and straightforward, thank you

Comment: Great, @Canovice! I was unsure, as I could not test it -- no `rda` file to test.